# installed conda package fails to import

Tags: python, environment

Im using `anaconda` to install packages and manage my environments on macOS Mojave 10.14.2.

I installed a new package `wget` at the terminal

```
conda install wget
```

When I run `conda list` the package shows up and I get no errors.

However, when I run

```
import wget
```

In `spyder` or `jupyter notebook` I get and error:

```
File "<ipython-input-28-1d5f1c9c9a6b>", line 7, in <module> import 
wget ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wget'
```

The package also shows up in my base(root) environment, so I have no idea why `spyder` or `jupyter notebook` can't find the package.

Answer (score 2):

Your command `conda install wget` installs wget for use at the conda prompt. To install wget for import in Python, you need to install a different package:

```
conda install -c anaconda pywget
```

In Python it's still:

```
import wget
```

Answer (score 0):

in conda prompt run this command and import , it will work

```
conda install -c anaconda wget
```